# I can't get flashvars from flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am trying to initialize some flash variable through swfobject oject, through javascript:

```
var flashvars = {param: "one"};
var params = {};
var attributes = {};
attributes.id = "as3_js";
swfobject.embedSWF("test.swf", "alt", "450", "450", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

And i Flex 4 i am trying, but my_param never gets the value from flashvars and never alerted:

```
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" creationComplete="initApp()">

public function initApp():void 
{
    var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
    var icon_url:String;
    icon_url = paramObj['param'];
    my_param = icon_url;
    Alert.show(my_param);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find solution @skabir mentioned link. Here just mention where mistake made You can use FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication instead of LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).

```
public function initApp():void 
{
    var paramObj:Object = Application(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication).parameters;
    var my_param:String = paramObj['param'];
    Alert.show(my_param);
}
```